# SQL query, check year on one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my MySQL table showing year.
Example:

```
Table: Information

ID | Year_sold
--- --------
1  | 2002-2010
2  | 2005-2015
3  | 2011-____
4  | 1975-1978
```

I will ask the table if it has data to show for a specific year.
Example:

`SELECT * FROM Information WHERE Year_sold = '2012';`

This will of course not work, but how can I type the SQL query if the result should be ID 2 and 3.

If the item is still active and being sold, the years will be shown like ID 3, "2011-____". I can replace the "____" if needed.

Comment: create a `sqlfiddle` ill see what i can do

Comment: This is bad table design.  Store each year in separate column or better yet in a separate row.

Comment: Changing table design will let you to use `NULL` instead of `____`, which is much simpler to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `BETWEEN`, `LEFT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions.

```
SELECT ID, Year_sold
FROM Information
WHERE '2012' BETWEEN LEFT(Year_sold,4) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(Year_sold,'-',-1)
```

Output

```
ID  Year_sold
2   2005-2015
3   2011-____
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7df7b7/1/0

If possible I would start again with your table structure and have something like:

Table: Information

```
ID | Year_sold_from | Year_sold_to
--- ------------------------------
1  | 2002           | 2010
2  | 2005           | 2015
3  | 2011           | null
4  | 1975           | 1978
```

Comment: Very Nice Answer :)

Comment: I would prefer to make the table like you say, but it is not an option. Will be to much work each time the table gets updated.

Your answer is very good and works fine! Had no idea this was possible, but can you please explain what you check here?

SUBSTRING_INDEX(Year_sold,'-',-1)

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(Year_sold,'-',-1)` returns everything after the `-` character.